# Where do cPanel cron jobs run from?

Tags: cron

Does anyone know the folder where cPanel cron jobs are ran from? I was using a command that stores the contents and now I need to flush that data out of that folder. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron jobs run out of the home folder of the user.